# Creating an external sharing report programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp, microsoft-graph

I need to create a report detailing external users and what they have access to on SharePoint sites. I suspect exactly like this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharing-reports

I need to do this within an application, is there a way of generating this report using PnP/Graph?

Edit: I'm almost certain this is the report I need but I need to pull it into an application, is there a way of accessing it through Graph? I see it's not listed as one of the available reports in the Graph API. Is there another way?

Edit 2: I'm writing a .NET app using PnP.Core and Graph so any pointers on what to go over for this info would be most appreciated if there's not already an exposed Report. Either that or pointers to articles, at this point it feels like I've read everything!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API is expanding for sure, as compared to 3 years ago. It will expand further for sure as I feel that all the UI features in Office 365 were built on top of Graph API.

I personally never tried this, but from the documentation, you can focus on `/reports` of the Graph API. Browse at this link: [SharePoint Activity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0).

You might want to combine between `/reports/getSharePointActivityUserDetail(period='D30')` and `/reports/getSharePointActivityUserCounts(period='D30')`. Note that both APIs will generate a CSV file temporary download link which you can download and process further. I suggest you use Power Automate to trigger instead.

Still troublesome, but better than nothing.